# ERROR in Type NgbdModalContent in propertylist/propertylist.component.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules

Tags: angular

I am using NgbdModalContent and PropertylistComponent classes inside the  property component and I am getting the below error while giving production build. everything is working fine in `ionic serve --open` but while giving the production build causing the issue.

I have created propertylist.component.module.ts to export 
    NgbdModalContent. I will explain everything in code.

Here I am using propertylistComponent.

### propertylist.component.html

```
   <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let policy of table let i = index">
        <td style="font-weight:700">{{policy.propertyid}}</td>
        <td (click)="propertydetail(policy)">{{policy.surveyor}} 
        </td>
        <td>{{policy.builder}}</td>
        <td style="font-weight:700">{{policy.project}}</td>
        <td>{{policy.projecttype}}</td>
        <td>{{policy.Units}}</td>
        <td>{{policy.floors}}</td>
        <td>{{policy.Added_date}}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center" (click)="datapolicy(policy)"> 
         <img src= "/assets/image/location.svg" alt="" style="width: 17px;
            height: 21px;
            object-fit: contain;
            opacity: 0.79;"></td>
       </tr>
  </tbody>
```

### propertylist.component.ts

```
        import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';

        import { NgbActiveModal, NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


        @Component({
          selector: 'ngbd-modal-content',
          template: `
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title">Location Details</h4>
              <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
           <b>Project Name</b>: {{policy.project}}<br>
           <b>Address</b>: <br>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Close</button>
            </div>
          `
        })
        export class NgbdModalContent {
          @Input() policy:any; 

          constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {}
        }
        @Component({
          selector: 'app-propertylist',
          templateUrl: './propertylist.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./propertylist.component.scss']
        })
        export class PropertylistComponent implements OnInit {

          order: string = 'propertyid';

          reverse: boolean = false;
          table:any= []


          constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {
            this.table = [


            { propertyid: 1,project:'sun',surveyor:'Rohit Patil', builder:"Mukesh", projecttype:"Residential", Units:34, floors:4, Added_date:"Dec 1993" },
              { propertyid: 2,project:'Mehul Test',surveyor:'Rohit Shetty',builder:"Rahul", projecttype:"Residential", Units:35, floors:4, Added_date:"Dec 1993" },
              { propertyid: 3,project:'SNMP',surveyor:'Rohit Patil1', builder:"Rahul", projecttype:"Residential", Units:36, floors:4, Added_date:"Dec 1993" },
              { propertyid: 4,project:'GSTC',surveyor:'pk Patil', builder:"Mukesh", projecttype:"Residential", Units:37, floors:4, Added_date:"Dec 1993" },
              { propertyid: 5,project:'sun1',surveyor:'cl Patil', builder:"Mukesh", projecttype:"Residential", Units:38, floors:4, Added_date:"Dec 1993" },
              { propertyid: 6,project:'sun2',surveyor:'Rohit Patil', builder:"Mukesh", projecttype:"Residential", Units:34, floors:4, Added_date:"Dec 1993" },
              { propertyid: 7,project:'sun3',surveyor:'Rohit Patil', builder:"Mukesh", projecttype:"Residential", Units:34, floors:4, Added_date:"Dec 1993" },
              { propertyid: 8,project:'sun4',surveyor:'Rohit Patil', builder:"Mukesh", projecttype:"Residential", Units:34, floors:4, Added_date:"Dec 1993" },
              { propertyid: 9,project:'sun5',surveyor:'Rohit Patil', builder:"Mukesh", projecttype:"Residential", Units:34, floors:4, Added_date:"Dec 1993" },
              { propertyid: 10,project:'sun',surveyor:'Rohit Patil', builder:"Mukesh",  Units:34, floors:4, Added_date:"Dec 1993" },
            ]
               datapolicy(policy: object){
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.policy = policy;
  } 

           }
```

### propertylist.component.module.ts

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

    import { NgbdModalContent, PropertylistComponent } from './pendingpropertylist.component';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [BrowserModule, NgbModule],
      declarations: [NgbdModalContent, PropertylistComponent],
      exports: [NgbdModalContent],
      bootstrap: [NgbdModalContent],
      entryComponents: [PropertylistComponent]
    })
    export class NgbdModalComponentModule {}
```

### app.module.ts

```
    import { NgbdModalContent, PropertylistComponent} from 
   './pendingpropertylist/pendingpropertylist.component';

    @NgModule({

    declarations: [
    PropertylistComponent,
    NgbdModalContent
   ],

    imports: [
    NgbModule
    ]

    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
     entryComponents: [PropertylistComponent,NgbdModalContent]
```

**Error that I am getting after ng build --prod is**

> ERROR in Type NgbdModalContent in
>
> /home/hh/vibeeportal/src/app/pendingpropertylist/pendingpropertylist.component.ts
>   is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in
>   /home/hh/vibeeportal/src/app/app.module.ts and
>   NgbdModalComponentModule in
>   /home/hh/vibeeportal/src/app/pendingpropertylist/pendingpropertylist.component.module.ts!
>   Please consider moving NgbdModalContent in
>   /home/hh/vibeeportal/src/app/pendingpropertylist/pendingpropertylist.component.ts
>   to a higher module that imports AppModule in
>   /home/hh/vibeeportal/src/app/app.module.ts and
>   NgbdModalComponentModule in
>   /home/hh/vibeeportal/src/app/pendingpropertylist/pendingpropertylist.component.module.ts.
>   You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes
>   NgbdModalContent in
>   /home/hh/vibeeportal/src/app/pendingpropertylist/pendingpropertylist.component.ts
>   then import that NgModule in AppModule in
>   /home/hh/vibeeportal/src/app/app.module.ts and
>   NgbdModalComponentModule in
>   /home/hh/vibeeportal/src/app/pendingpropertylist/pendingpropertylist.component.module.ts.

Comment: Remove the pendingpropertylist module from app.module.ts declaration. As you are going to use Lazy loading its likely you need to declare your variable in on module.

Comment: can u be more specific please. if I will remove pendingpropertylist module from app.module.ts then how I will load pendingpropertylist component

Comment: Are you using Angular `LazyLoading`? if yes then When  `NgbdModalComponentModule` Module is loaded its auto loaded its component. If you are not using lazy loading then removed the `PropertylistComponent` from the `NgbdModalComponentModule` module and it will work.

Comment: Here I am not using lazy loading and now I have removed PropertylistComponent from NgbdModalComponentModule but still error is exist. import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { NgbdModalContent } from './pendingpropertylist.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, NgbModule],
  declarations: [NgbdModalContent],
  exports: [NgbdModalContent],
  bootstrap: [NgbdModalContent],
  entryComponents: []
})
export class NgbdModalComponentModule {}

Answer (score 0):

As you are stated you are not using `Angular LazyLoading` you need to modify as written below:

> propertylist.component.html

Will be same

> propertylist.component.ts

Will be same

> propertylist.component.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { NgbdModalContent, PropertylistComponent } from './pendingpropertylist.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, NgbModule],
  declarations: [NgbdModalContent // Remove this -> , PropertylistComponent],
  exports: [NgbdModalContent],
  bootstrap: [NgbdModalContent],
  //Remove this-> entryComponents: [PropertylistComponent]
})
export class NgbdModalComponentModule {}
```

> app.module.ts

```
import { NgbdModalContent, PropertylistComponent} from 
   './pendingpropertylist/pendingpropertylist.component';

    @NgModule({

    declarations: [
    PropertylistComponent,
   // Remove this -> NgbdModalContent
   ],

    imports: [
    NgbModule,
    add this -> NgbdModalComponentModule 
    ]

    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
     entryComponents: [PropertylistComponent // Remove this->,NgbdModalContent]
```

> **EDITED: With LazyLoading**
>
> app.module.ts

```
import { NgbdModalContent, PropertylistComponent} from 
   './pendingpropertylist/pendingpropertylist.component';

    @NgModule({

    declarations: [
    // Remove this -> PropertylistComponent,
   // Remove this -> NgbdModalContent
   ],

    imports: [
    NgbModule,
    add this -> NgbdModalComponentModule 
    ]

    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
     entryComponents: [// Remove this -> PropertylistComponent // Remove this->,NgbdModalContent]
```

> propertylist.component.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { NgbdModalContent, PropertylistComponent } from './pendingpropertylist.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, NgbModule],
  declarations: [NgbdModalContent, PropertylistComponent],
  exports: [NgbdModalContent],
  bootstrap: [NgbdModalContent],
  entryComponents: [PropertylistComponent]
})
export class NgbdModalComponentModule {}
```

After this you need to add route:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'propertyList', loadChildren: './NgbdModalComponent.module#NgbdModalComponentModule'}
];
```

That's it. Happy coding ;)